# Is there a better suggestion for web design container width?

Tags: design, web

So we know the majority screen sizes research already, 
[image]

But what are the optimal **max-width** suggestion for the container in each of screen sizes?

I can only find a suggestion report like this,
[image]
from here:http://www.visionefx.net/website-pixel-width-safe-area.htm

How you think? what are your suggestions or what you are following?

Comment: I just reviewed the recent questions, because I recall a very similar one in the past few days—but I cannot find it. Sorry. It had some great responses.

Comment: oops, could you give a keyword?

Comment: I'm confused. Why are screen resolutions important here? I mean, why not just got the responsive approach and accommodate for all screen sizes? Just design to bootstrap's standards.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? 'Safe' area widths might be useful in creating pixel-perfect PSD's, but in developing CSS you want to design responsively, not limit yourself to fixed container widths.

Answer (score 3):

Never design any element to any screen size cause, eventually, another will come out or take its place. Make your design responsive and adaptive to changing widths. When it starts to look like crap, that is your breakpoint.

Doing it any other way is impossible and will only drive you crazy.